# View Android database indices

Tags: android, sqlite, indices

I am adding indices to database tables on creation by executing queries such as

`CREATE INDEX "matchcode" on wholesaler_material (matchcode ASC);`

I want to make sure that the indices have been added. Is there a way to confirm so? DDMS of Eclipse does not give me any hint as regards indices.

Thank you in advance for you assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query `sqlite_master`:

```
SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='index' AND name='matchcode';
```

This will return a result row if there was an index with the given name and nothing otherwise.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='index' AND name='matchcode'` did the trick. Thanks.